# Problems with For Loop syntax and variables

Tags: php, for-loop

I have multiple variables named `day1Name`, `day2Name`, `day3Name`, and so on. I also have `exercise_11_Name`, `exercise_12_name`, etc.

I have a lot of those, and the value I want to save in those variables depends on user input.

I don't want to have to write `$variableName = $_POST['name'`] for every single one because it's a lot and a terrible practice. Therefore, I want to use a `for` loop so my code looks cleaner.

What I am trying to accomplish is something similar to this I believe:

```
for(i=0, i<10; i++)
{
   $day[i+1]name = $_POST['day[i+1]name']; 
   $exercise_1[i+1]_name = $_POST['excName1[i]']; 
}
```

I know the way I wrote it is not going to work though.

P.S. Where I wrote `[i+1]` is where I just need the number, for example, `$day[i+1]name` should become the variable `$day1name` when `i=0`. Where I wrote `[i]`, for example `excName1[i]`, that's an array in which I want to retrieve the value of that specific index.

I would really appreciate some help in this.

Thanks! =]

Comment: Is it possible to put all the `day` variables in a data structure and then iterate through that? I don't think it's possible to construct a variable reference from a string name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an array named $day_name, and name your form fields day_name_1, day_name_2 etc

then in your loop:
    $day_name[$i+1] = $_POST['day_name_' . ($i + 1)]

do the same with the exercise variables.
I assume it is php, so your loop variable has to be $i, not i

Comment: Yes, I am using php. I'll give that a shot and I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: For the exercise, would it be something similar to this: $exercise_name_1[$i+1] = $_POST['exc_name_' . ($i + 1).'[$i]']? Is the POST part correct?

Comment: acutally more like:
    $exercise_name[$i+1] = $_POST['exc_name_' . ($i + 1)];

your form fields are numbered in the same way: exc_name_1, exc_name_2, etc

Comment: Everything is working fine now, EXCEPT for the exercise part.

'code' $exercise_name1[$i] = $_POST['excName1['.$i.']'];

Yes, excName is an array. I'm using a Jquery library to dynamically add or remove fields, therefore, I need to name those input fields as an array. I cannot, however, get their values using the above code. Is anything wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0):

The solution you are asking for is called somewhat variable variable or variable expansion and goes on like this:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
   $d=$i+1;
   ${"day{$d}name"} = $_POST["day{$d}name"];
   ${"exercise_1{$d}_name"} = $_POST["excName1{$i}"];
}
```

However I encourage you to look at "array" which is somehow what @Bart suggested above, which is probably a better way of organizing your data around.